# Summing using the group function with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've got a collection with entries that look like this:

```
thing1 = {"number": "0001", "param1":"521", "param2":"5", "param3":"3.2"}
```

I want to go through and sum together param3 from every entry in the collection. Here's my attempt at doing that:

```
db.data.group('param3', 'param3':$exists, 'sum':0, 'function(doc, out) {out.sum += doc.param3;})
```

I'm getting a syntax error here ("Missing ) after argument list"), but I'm not sure that group call is logically correct.

Comment: The following question may help: [how to use “group” in pymongo to group similar rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010624/how-to-use-group-in-pymongo-to-group-similar-rows).